# Querying a Multiple Select Box

Tags: php, mysql

I'm curious as to how you can insert the selected items into a database when you don't know exactly how many options a user may select.

Say I have the following code:

```
<select name="foo[]" multiple="multiple">
     <option value="dog">Dog</option>
     <option value="cat">Cat</option>
     <option value="fish">Fish</option>
</select>

<?php

$pets = $_POST['foo'];

$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `pets` (`pet1`, `pet2`, `pet3`) VALUES ('".$pets[0]."', '".$pets[1]."',  '".$pets[2]."')");
?>
```

And the user selects only the option 'dog', or 'dog' and 'cat', or 'cat' and 'dog', etc. Basically any combination of the three.

Would I have to hard-code the query to accept all possible options and then specify a WHERE clause saying "`WHERE $pets != ''`" or something similar?

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Store a serialized string instead.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @j08691 I looked up an example of serialize() and I don't understand how that can help in knowing how many pets the user selected, and therefore how many to insert into the database? I was looking at this example (http://www.webmaster-source.com/2009/02/15/php-serialize-function/) and I don't understand how that helps, could you please explain?

Comment: Thank you guys for the help, I think I found my answer here: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534939/getting-data-from-a-multiple-select-dropdown-with-php-to-insert-into-mysql?rq=1). Basically I need a foreach loop with key/value pairs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, do not use **mysql_*** functions because are **deprecated**

If you need to insert them in multiple rows you can simply use loop like this

```
foreach($pets as $pet)
{
      Insert to db each single pet in different row 
}
```

If you want to insert them in the same row you can use

```
$toInsert = implode(',',$pets);
```

put if you have n numbers of columns which i don't think you can use the 2nd option and the implode function for number of pets

```
$petsColumns = array(); 

for($i = 1; $i <= count($pets); $i++) 
     $petsColumns[] = "pet".$i ; 

$petsColumnsString = implode(',',$petsColumns);
```

And concate them to the query

If hope this can help of what you are trying to do

Comment: Thank you, I think the first option is what I need, with the addition of key/value pairs

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options for this situation.

First, you could store the data as a serialized string.  This is fine if you only need to use the data on the PHP side.  The main downside is that MySQL won't really understand the data, so it can't filter the data before it gets to PHP.

The second option is a `SET` data type column.  the `SET` data type allows you to have any combination of possible options while making the database more aware of the data.  There is a limit of 64 members in a `SET`.  The `SET` option is the smallest option, but filtering on the column is not optimal.  Changing the possible values is also a bit difficult.

The third option is to normalize the values to a separate table.  You would have the users table and a pets table.  The pets table would have the user ID, a pet column, and a unique ID for the table.  Then you would just insert a row into the pets table for each entry the user select.  This allows you to have as many entries per user and allow you to easily filter on the data.  This is usually the best way to go.  It's probably also a good idea to normalize the possible pet values into a third table.  That table would have a pet ID, pet name, and whatever else you might want with it.  The second table would then act as a bridge between the users and pets, having the user ID, pet ID, and a unique ID for the table.