# Insert multiple form selections into one single table column (set)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

I have a simple form with the following:

```
<form action="#" method="post" name="form1" >
    <input name="criteria1" size="64">
    <input name="criteria2" size="64">
    <select name="criteria3[]"multiple="multiple" >
        <option value="5 ">5</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Now, if the user selects more then one option from criteria3, how do I insert that in a single database table field as well as insert the other two criteria in their own column?

I have tried many different ways and just get no where. My last attempt was as follows:

```
$values = array();

$type = explode(",", $_POST['criteria3']);

foreach ($type as $value) {
    $values[] = sprintf('(%d)', $value);
}

$values = implode(',', $values);

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {
   $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO table (name, date, number) 
                         VALUES (%s, %s, '$values')",
       GetSQLValueString($_POST['criteria1'], "text"),
       GetSQLValueString($_POST['criteria2'], "text"));
```

Not really sure what is going wrong – have tried several iterations and am getting no where.

Here are the most recent errors:

```
Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /filename.php on line 84

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /filename.php on line 86
```

Comment: that is becuase you `$_POST['criteria3']` is an array

Comment: @joe as `$_POST['criteria3']` is an array hence you need to run an insert query for each of the array elements individually and that I have implemented using a `foreach` loop. Read my answer.

Comment: @Rajesh - it seems that this is the only way to do this - yet, it is not really want I want - there has to be a way to just insert the entire array in the table column - just the data separated by commas.

Comment: @Joe would u please give the **database table structure**? The answer may lie there.

Comment: @joe, what is the datatype of the attribute `number`? The implementation with `implode` will only work with **string**-datatype. Which datatype is it?

Answer (score 0):

remove the explode function from $_POST['criteria3'], Because it is already array it not need of explode so you try directly

```
       $type = $_POST['criteria3'];

        foreach($type  as $k => $v) {
           // here do the INSERT query with value $v
      }
```

or if you prefer this link 
1).**[Getting data from a multiple select dropdown with PHP to insert into MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534939/getting-data-from-a-multiple-select-dropdown-with-php-to-insert-into-mysql)**

hope this helpful for you :)

```
          <form action="" method="post" name="form1" >
<input name="criteria1" size="64">
<input name="criteria2" size="64">
<select name="criteria3[]" multiple >
<option value="5 ">5</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
</select>
```

```
       <?php
   if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
    $criteria1 = $_POST['criteria1'];
    $criteria2 = $_POST['criteria2'];
    if(isset($_POST['criteria3']))
     {
       $query = "insert into table_name (criteria1, criteria2, criteria3) values";
        foreach($_POST['criteria3'] as $list)
         {
          $query .= "('$criteria1','$criteria2','$list')";
          }
         echo $query;                       
     }
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: I will remove the explode - my idea was to take each element out of the array and then try to insert them separately. Did not work. I did check out the link you provided - even read it before asking my question here and it did not work as it tried to create a record for each iteration of criteria3 and I got duplicate records.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following(If you want **separate records** corresponding to separate values for `criteria3` for a single entity):

```
$criteria1 = $_POST['criteria1'];
$criteria2 = $_POST['criteria2'];
$arr=$_POST['criteria3'];
foreach($arr as $criteria3)
{
    $sql="insert into table_name (criteria1, criteria2, criteria3) values('".$criteria1."', '".$criteria2."', '".$criteria3."')";
    mysql_query($sql);
}
```

And if you want a **single record** for a single entity with multiple `criteria3`-values use the following code:

```
$criteria1 = $_POST['criteria1'];
$criteria2 = $_POST['criteria2'];
if(isset($_POST['criteria3'])) //true when at least on of the options is selected.
{
    $criteria3=implode(',', $_POST['criteria3']);
}
else //i.e. when no option is selected.
{
    $criteria3='';
}
$sql="insert into table_name (criteria1, criteria2, criteria3) values('".$criteria1."', '".$criteria2."', '".$criteria3."')";
mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Thanks - however, I do not want to insert criteria1 and critieria2 with each iteration of criteria3. So, if criteria1 is a name, criteria2 is a date and criteria3 is an array of (one, two, three) - then i am trying to insert as one (1) record the following - [name]; [date]; [one, two, three] - all in one table record - not sure this works that way as it seems to want to create a new record for each iteration of criteria3.

Comment: @Joe check it now. It incorporates both the approaches.

Comment: Thanks. This looks a lot better for what I want. I have tried this already - several times and only get an error around the implode statement. But, this is what I want and will continue to work with it until I get it right. @Rajesh

Answer (score 0):

Since I am the only one that will be inserting data - I found a crude work around until I can get the code that Rajesh provided to work - I think this is the right path if I can get it to work.Thanks to all for your input. If I could, I would give you all the up vote!

Answer (score -1):

Explode only works with a string.
What you get from your form for criteria3 is an array, so you should act accordingly:

```
$criteria1 = $_POST['criteria1'];
$criteria2 = $_POST['criteria2'];
$criteria3 = implode(",", $_POST['criteria3']);
```

Here we generate a string based on the content of the table returned by your form.
We seperate each element by a comma.

Then we create the SQL query.

```
$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO table (name, date, number) VALUES (%s, %s, %s);", $criteria1, $criteria2, $criteria3);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I like this as I think I understand it - yet, when i tried it, all I got was this Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in /filename.php on line 82

Comment: There has to be a way to take the array from the form say (one, two, three) and just simply place (insert) it in a table column as a whole (one, two, three) and not have three separate records for each item in the array.

Comment: @RajeshPaul That's why I first imploded it.

Comment: @Joe Can you give if the type of argument you get? Normally, if your form is using something like this: name="criteria3[]", you should get an array and should be able to implode it... Perhaps can you try without the brackets: name="criteria3" and tell us what type of argument you get.